# Manufacturing with glass panels

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, industrial-engineering, product-engineering, production-technology

I would like to design a 3.2-inch LCD display onto a product. The best aesthetic I have seen is using a flush glass screen front face.

[image]

My product does not use touch screen. How would I go about sourcing say 4-inch glass panels? Is this sort of thing available somewhere off the shelf? Or is it something that you need to get made custom?

Comment: Google for "LCD screen protector". If you are using a standard size LCD there should be products available to match the size.

Comment: Let me clarify. What if I want 10,000 of them customised with a logo

Comment: Then just google "Glass screen protector Alibaba"

Comment: This is a shopping question not an engineering one.

Comment: Guys, I don't own 10,000 phones! I want to know how to manufacture or otherwise get my grubby hands on custom glass sheets.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: @monkey At those quantities, most manufacturers would jump at the chance. Just find one and ask.